# tkinter list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I get error like this in the title when I run this code. I want to make TODO list but I'm getting many errors on my way `:(`. I can't call array (`tab`) in other function and I can't change column in checkbox `grid`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msb
win = Tk()
win.title("Checkbutton")
win.geometry("300x600")
win.resizable("False","False")
task_name = StringVar()
tab = []
tab.append("")
tab.append("")
r = 2
c = 1
cc = IntVar

def checking():
        tab[r].grid(row=r, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(5, 5))

def addcheck():
    global r
    global c
    global cc

    if r < 16:
        tab.append(Checkbutton(variable = cc, text = task_name.get(), command = checking))
        tab[r].grid(row=r, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(5, 5))
        r = r + 1
        task_entry.delete(0, 20)
    else:
        msb.showwarning(title="DANGER", message="TOO MUCH TASKS, TAKE A REST")

text1 = Label(win, text = "TO DO:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = (10, 10), pady = (30, 10))
text2 = Label(win, text = "DONE: ").grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = (10, 10), pady = (30, 10))

task_entry = Entry(width = "20", textvariable = task_name)
task_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = (30, 10))
add = Button(win, text = "add task", command = addcheck).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = (10, 10))

mainloop()
```

Full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\pythonprojekty\pythonProject\main.py", line 18, in checking
    tab[r].grid(row=r, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(5, 5))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what is the error (provide a full error traceback starting from word "Traceback") and as I have already mentioned the pattern `var = Widget(...).<layout_manager>(...)` is a bad pattern

Comment: add to your question (you can [edit] it) and NOT in comments, they are not formatted otherwise (and also delete the comment after placing that info in the question) and you don't understand what pattern I was talking about, also why are you appending two empty strings to that list? also `r` is changing so using `tab[r]` will anyways give you the last item in that list

Comment: i added two empty strings cuz I've wanted to start from third row in grid

Comment: i just want to change column in selected checkbutton to 1 from 0

Comment: just use `Frame`s, then you will be able to start from 0th row in the frame also your index is one element to high, for example if a list contains 2 elements to access the second element you need to use `[1]`

Comment: dude, idk, u dont get the problem I think.

Comment: look, i just want to change the grid in other function

Comment: I think the easiest is to simply add another item to that list (that should fix the index error)

Comment: Try using `tab[r] = Checkbutton(...` instead of `tab.append(Checkbutton(...`, or `tab[-1].grid(...` instead of `tab[r].grid(...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `IndexError` because of trying to use the global variable `r` in the `checking()` function — and the way to fix it is by explicitly passing the `row` value as an argument when calling it. In the code below this is being done by using a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression to define the callback `command=` function.

There were a number of other mistakes in your code, and I have attempted to correct them all and reformat the code to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations for readability.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msb
from tkinter.constants import *


win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Checkbutton")
win.geometry("300x600")
win.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

task_name = tk.StringVar()
tab = [None, None]
r = len(tab)

def checking(row):
    tab[row].grid(row=row, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(5, 5))


def addcheck():
    global r

    if r > 16:
        msb.showwarning(title="DANGER", message="TOO MANY TASKS, TAKE A REST")
    else:
        cb_var = tk.IntVar()
        tab.append(tk.Checkbutton(variable=cb_var, text=task_name.get(),
                                  command=lambda row=r: checking(row)))
        tab[r].grid(row=r, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(5, 5))
        r += 1
        task_entry.delete(0, END)


tk.Label(win, text="TO DO:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(30, 10))
tk.Label(win, text="DONE: ").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(30, 10))

task_entry = tk.Entry(width="20", textvariable=task_name)
task_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(30, 10))
tk.Button(win, text="add task", command=addcheck).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10, 10))

task_entry.focus_set()
win.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it running on my system:

[image: screenshot]